# Fetch elapsed time value from a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I need to fetch elapsed time output from file. I need the value just before "elapsed" that is `2:10:42`.

File content :

```
312.90user 15.57system 2:10:42elapsed 4%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (1major+152440minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Comment: That looks like GNU `time` output. You could use `time --format=%e` then

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please Accept it with the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Relatively easy with Perl:

```
perl -n -E '/([0-9:]+)elapsed/ and say $1' «FILE»
```

Note that just looks for a time-like thing before the word "elapsed" (without any spaces). That may suffer from a false-positive if applied to other files. Also, it'll check each line in the file (and print any elapsed time found), not just the first.

Answer (score 0):

On lines that contain "(time)elapsed", search for "(anything) (space) (time)elapsed(anything)" and replace everything with "(time)", and then print the resulting line:

```
sed -n '/[0-9:]*elapsed/ { s/.* \([0-9:]*\)elapsed.*/\1/;p }' input > output
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

Assuming your data is in a file named *file* you can do this:

```
$ head -1 file | awk '{ print $3 }' | sed 's/elapsed//'
```

And it will return: `2:10:42`

---

Breaking it down:

Grab the first line of your file with:

```
head -1 file
```

The heavy lifting is done by *awk*:

```
awk '{ print $3 }'
```

which just prints the third data block `2:10:42elapsed`.

Then use the *sed* string editor to tidy up:

```
sed 's/elapsed//'
```

---

You can redirect the output anywhere you like, for example, just add:

```
> output.text
```

to output `2:10:42` to a file named *output.txt*

The above will clobber (replace) any content in the *output.txt* file. If you want to append your data to the end of your file instead just use `>>` instead of `>`.